# Random library not functioning when running a file from a terminal.

Tags: command-line, python, output

I've recently decided to start learning to program using python. The book I was using is teaching me about libraries now. So I tried running the code below:

```
import random
random.randint(1, 10)
```

I've tried running this after building it both in gedit and geany using  python filename.py and python3 filename.py to execute my program from the terminal and it doesn't display a random number. The terminal IDLE for python generates a random number as it should however. Would anyone be nice enough to help a newbie to both Linux and python out? Any and all help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Outside of the interactive python shell, you need to tell python to *print* the value e.g. `print (random.randint(1, 10))`

Comment: @steeldriver I think that should be an answer ;)

Comment: Probably off-topic, since you could have the exact same question for any linux distro or even windows. (I didn't think of that at first)

Comment: @NonnyMoose I just thought it was fitting because I thought it had to do with a setting related to the terminal or any of the other features I was using.

Comment: @steeldriver this worked. Thank you very much for your help. I wouldn't have known that I needed to use the print function because the book I'm using just says that it should work but it's basing it off of the Python IDLE. As I said I'm still new to Ubuntu and thought this was a software issue related not a programming one. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that Python needs to print the output of `random.randint`. It wasn't an issue with the software just a programming one. For anyone else who has the same problem as me, here is what the code should look like:

```
import random

print(random.randint(1, 10))
```

Comment: Just an FYI, but if you had executed this from within a `python3` interactive terminal, you wouldn't have needed the `print` statement.  However, you can simplify this by getting rid of the `random.rantint(a,b)` after the `import` and just use the one you're using within the `print` call.

Comment: @ThomasWard I've taken the liberty of editing out the superfluous evaluation

Comment: @Thomas Ward I didn't know that. Thank you. As I stated I'm still new to linux and programming overall and the book I'm using is just using an IDLE. The more I can learn about how to write effective python code and make it neat the better it is for me.